# Where can I find the parts for a Shiskebab?

Tags: fallout-3

I am looking for parts for a shiskebab, I have the schematic but the parts are not sold in megaton.

Comment: Looks to be answered on a forum [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/939933-fallout-3/46249406) but I can't fact check to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build the Shishkebab you need:

- [Motorcycle gas tank](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Motorcycle_gas_tank), there are 5 located in the Minefield
- [Motorcycle handbreake](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Motorcycle_handbrake), again two are located in the Minefield ( Each is located near the burned out remains of a motorcycle, along with a motorcycle gas tank. One is on the east side of the Gillian house, and the other is on the southwest side of the Benson house.)
- [Pilot light](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pilot_light) - can be taken from any oven - again check the Minefield or SuperDuperMart
- [Lawnmower blade](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lawn_mower_blade) which again, can be find on (surprise, surprise) lawnmowers in the Minefield.

In short: go to [Minefield](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Minefield).

[image]